# How to make a full adder using 1/4 DEMUXs and 1 NOR gate?

Tags: digital-logic

I was supposed to make a full adder circuit of two 1 bit numbers using any amount of 1/4 demultiplexers and only one NOR gate with arbitrary number of inputs.I have no idea how to do this.Is such thing even possible?With just one NOR gate you can have either a carry bit output or a sum bit output, not both.How does one approach a problem like this one?What's the general procedure?

Comment: There isn't a general procedure. This is a puzzle-type problem, not the kind of thing that you'll actually encounter in real design. Still fun if you like puzzles :)

Comment: I don't think there is a general procedure here. Start with each FA function distinctly and see how you can implement with the given constraints.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I did, I've spent over 1 hour and still have no clue if this is even possible with given constraints.Considering how there's (almost) infinite amount of things that can be done and only one of them is correct, this is pretty difficult.

Comment: @JoeDough I agree. I don't have a solution from the top of my mind as well. If you ask me if it is a good exercise that is teaching any useful engineering skill - I would say no.

Comment: Is the NOR gate to provide the combination of the Carry bits?

Comment: Are you trying to make a 1-bit full adder out of any number of demuxes plus just one NOR? Or are you trying to make an N-bit adder out of any number of demuxes plus just one NOR for the entire N-bit adder? I'm not sure I'm clear on the question. (Everyone else seems to know. But I'm not sure.)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf it can be used for anything as long as it is used only once.

Comment: @jonk a 1 bit full adder (two 1 bit numbers + 3rd bit) using as many demuxes as needed and just one NOR gate.

Comment: @JoeDough Oh. That's easy, isn't it? (I thought this was a hard problem, from reading.)

Comment: @jonk it wasn't easy to me for some reason.Basically I tried to find the solution using solutions that worked on other problems (as if I was a machine learning algorithm -.-).

Comment: @JoeDough Okay. And I admit I had a hard time reading your words with clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dumb, but a universal approach would be to use the demux to implement a universal gate such as `NOR`. Each demux can implement 4 different functions of two variables on the following way:

```
     |^^^^^^|
     |      |--- A'B'
1 ---|      |--- A'B
     |      |--- AB'
     |      |--- AB
     |______|
       |  |
       A  B
```

Notice `A'B'`. It is the same as `(A+B)'`, which is... `NOR`! 
So this proves that the task *is* possible and doable (or a stronger claim - that *any* logical function can be implemented using 1-4 demuxes).

As a bonus you can get an `AND` gate and two components of `XOR` out of it, which will significantly reduce the number of such a a units in the final circuit.

**Note**
If you are not allowed to use constants such as `1`, you can utilize the provided single `NOR` gate connected to the two of the demux outputs as following:

```
     |^^^^^^|
     |      |---______
A ---|      |---\ NOR \____
     |      |---/_____/
     |      |---
     |______|
       |  |
       A  A
```

Since these two outputs will be low for any `A`, the `NOR` will output `1` always.

Comment: This scheme reminds me of how FPGA logic units work, only they use multiplexers and constants instead.

Comment: @Hearth Well, multiplexers a *much* more convenient in terms of arbitrary logical function implementation...

Comment: I haven't considered making standard logic gates at all (for some reason I thought it wasn't possible), cramming all the logic into as few demuxes as possible obviously wasn't a good idea.How did you approach this problem?Where did you start from and why?I'm interested in your thought process from reading the problem to finding a solution.

Comment: @JoeDough Well, obviously it is not a full solution, but a somewhat general method. You could start with writing down the functions of demux in general and identify which variables you could fix and which to use as an input to get something useful. At first I though  about using the `AND` function and one of the other functions to implement `NOT` and have it combined into `NAND`, but then, when I started to write the answer I was that there is a ready to use `NOR`.

Comment: The second part - about getting constant `1` was kind of intuitive. It is obvious that you can't get it out of demux alone no matter what the inputs are, if they are variable. Meaning that you need something to combine these. The only thing that we have here is this `NOR`. Now, `NOR` requires two low inputs to produce `1`. Now you only need to find two inputs that will always be low, while feeding it any input. The choice of feeding `A` was arbitrary.

Comment: ..well, arbitrary except for the observation that when feeding two identical values in the control inputs the two "middle" outputs will never get "selected".